# .htaccess instructions ignored in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying include some instructions in .htaccess, but iy works only without wordpress rules.

it works:

```
cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(python|catexplorador) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

it doesn't work:

```
cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(python|catexplorador) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Could you help me?

Cheers,
Joao

Comment: What happens that makes you say it "doesn't work"? Does it give an error message? Show the wrong page?
Anyway, it works with my setup, so it's probably something specific about your site.

Comment: Hi! O could fixed the problem changing the .htaccess from public_html to outside this folder.